# ndb retrieving entity key by ID without parent

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I want to get an entity key knowing entity ID and an ancestor.
ID is unique within entity group defined by the ancestor.
It seems to me that it's not possible using ndb interface. As I understand datastore it may be caused by the fact that this operation requires full index scan to perform.
The workaround I used is to create a computed property in the model, which will contain the id part of the key. I'm able now to do an ancestor query and get the key

```
class SomeModel(ndb.Model):
    ID = ndb.ComputedProperty( lambda self: self.key.id() )

    @classmethod
    def id_to_key(cls, identifier, ancestor):
        return cls.query(cls.ID == identifier,
                         ancestor = ancestor.key ).get( keys_only = True)
```

It seems to work, but are there any better solutions to this problem?

**Update**
It seems that for datastore the natural solution is to use full paths instead of identifiers. Initially I thought it'd be too burdensome. After reading dragonx answer I redesigned my application. To my suprise everything looks much simpler now. Additional benefits are that my entities will use less space and I won't need additional indexes.

Comment: Sounds like you got the right answer!

Comment: ID is _not_ guaranteed unique within an entity group - only for a given parent entity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this problem too.  I think you do have the solution.

The better solution would be to stop using IDs to reference entities, and store either the actual key or a full path.

Internally, I use keys instead of IDs.

On my rest API, I used to do `http://url/kind/id` (where id looked like "123") to fetch an entity.  I modified that to provide the complete ancestor path to the entity:  `http://url/kind/ancestor-ancestor-id` (789-456-123), I'd then parse that string, generate a key, and then get by key.

Comment: You are right. Everything is easier with full ancestor path. It seems that this is the right way to do such things in datastore. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget there is a "key" type in the datastore you can use to store actual keys (KeyProperty).

Comment: In a side note, Java has [these methods](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory#keyToString%28com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key%29) to  serialize and deserialize keys

Comment: kurl = instance.key.urlsafe()  ->  instance = nb.Key(urlsafe=kurl) I know urlsafe() generates a ugly string but it makes the job

Answer (score 3):

Since you have full information about your ancestor and you know your id, you could directly create your key and get the entity, as follows:

```
my_key = ndb.Key(Ancestor, ancestor.key.id(), SomeModel, id)
entity = my_key.get()
```

This way you avoid making a query that costs more than a `get` operation both in terms of money and speed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is a good solution if ancestor is also a parent, but it's not my case

Comment: Since you used the term "ancestor", I thought you meant that it was a parent. If this is not the case, then your approach I think is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I want to make a little addition to dargonx's answer.

In my application on front-end I use string representation of keys:

```
str(instance.key())
```

When I need to make some changes with instence even if it is a descendant I use only string representation of its key. For example I have `key_str` -- argument from request to delete instance':

```
instance = Kind.get(key_str)
instance.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is using `urlsafe` to get item without worry about parent id:

```
pk = ndb.Key(Product, 1234)
usafe = LocationItem.get_by_id(5678, parent=pk).key.urlsafe()
# now can get by urlsafe
item = ndb.Key(urlsafe=usafe)
print item
```