# Can I use both a simple key and an ancestor key for the same entity type?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to store an entity type and I would like to query it once by its key (e.g. it's userID) and once by its parentKey (e.g. the adminUserID of userID). Is it a such thing possible?

I was thinking to create a key using the userID as key and then add the adminUserID as parent/ancestor key. Am I still able to get the entity by its "simple" key (userID) or I always need to create the key both from the ancestor key and the userID ?

Comment: A key is always made up of the full ancestor path.  However, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954899/ndb-retrieving-entity-key-by-id-without-parent may be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Once a key is created, it cannot be changed, i.e. you cannot add a parent to an existing entity (you'll have to delete it and create a new entity with a parent key). You can create a key with a non-existent parent, though, as long as you know its id beforehand.

Also note that children entities may have the same auto-generated ids if they belong to different parents.

I don't know your requirements, but you may be better off with a simple no-parent entity where parent id is just an indexed property. You can create such entities at any time, add parent ids at any time, and query both by id and/or parentId.